# Dynamically insert react components into another react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now I have a sidebar that I want to use for various forms and bits of information. I'm using the global event system to trigger the opening of the sidebar, but I'm not sure how to inject react components into the sidebar react component.

I started by trying this

```
componentWillMount: ->
  window.toggleSidebar = (react_component)=>
    React.renderComponent(react_component(), document.getElementById('sidebar-content'))
    @toggleSidebar()
```

But this didn't work once all of the components are mounted because you can't call render component into an element that is inside another component.

So is there an accepted way to pass any react component into another component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually want to pass a component instance, you want to pass the component factory and data that it can use to render the component.

```
events.emit('sidebar-change-request', {component: Foo, props: obj, open: true});
```

And in the sidebar component it'd be listening to the event:

```
  getInitialState: -> component: React.DOM.div, props: {}, open: false

  # standard event emitter stuff    
  componentDidMount: -> 
    events.addListener 'sidebar-change-request', this.handleSidebarChangeRequest

  componentWillUnmount: ->
    events.removeListener 'sidebar-change-request', this.handleSidebarChangeRequest

  # simply apply the payload to state
  handleSidebarChangeRequest: (payload) ->
    this.setState payload

  # dynamically render stuff
  render: ->
    if this.state.open
       React.DOM.div {className: "sidebar"},
          this.state.component this.state.props
    else
       React.DOM.div null
```

If you needed to get some information back from the component renered in the sidebar, you'd pass a callback to that components via props; or the component could emit events.

Comment: Thank you so much, this clears up a lot of things. I'm gonna go test it out. One thing though, what is that event system you are using? I'm somewhat new to global events and all of that. I am currently using a name spaced global event system, and I have seen others using backbones event system. Is that a different event system?

Comment: I usually use [node's EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html).  You can get it with `var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter, events = new EventEmitter()` if you're using browserify or similar.  There's also [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2) which you can easily get in npm or [standalone](http://wzrd.in/standalone/eventemitter2).